# Two perpendicular faces are highlighted as one (upon selection)

Tags: faces

Two perpendicular faces are highlighted as one upon selection. Actually the upper one is not recognized as a separate face at all (it lacks the dot in the middle). How has it happened and how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might be dealing with here is called an "ngon".  It's a shape that has more than four vertices.

It looks like you made a face of all of these verts with one <kbd>F</kbd> command *before* the top edge was made, or something similar.  So blender has done its best to draw it in a way that makes sense, but that *is* one face, technically.

It also looks like you have a couple of rogue edges down at the bottom.

In this case it's an easy fix, just select this top edge:

[image]

And hit <kbd>J</kbd> which is the shortcut for *Connect Vertex Path*.  It creates edges or splits faces where needed.

[image]

Comment: And what should I do with "rogue edges down at the bottom"? And how did they occur? Thank you!

Comment: just box select and delete them, when you're starting out you don't have a good grasp of the different modes, you might have been trying to do something related to object mode and didn't realize you duplicated an edge, or extruded a vertex or something.  They're pretty harmless since they don't have a face, so they won't affect your render, it's easy to not notice stuff like that